# Raising an issue after upgrading Django version

Tags: django

I upgraded my Django version from **3.1.2** to **3.2**.
But it gives me this error.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'api'. Check that 'apps.api.apps.ApiConfig.name' is correct.
```

Please give a suggestion.
Thank you.

Comment: pip instal -U Django==3.2

Comment: Just I tried it, but I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Please add the code that you're trying to run if you have any?

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem. In my example, I used app_name = "apps.api" as the app name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).